# How to write a pattern to a device to use it with badblocks with -t test_pattern option

Tags: hard-disk, badblocks

I recently bought a 4TB hard disk and I want to do a read-write `badblocks` test on this before I start using it. Since running `badblocks` with `-w` option would take ages for 4TB, I've thought to first write a pattern on the disk and then use the `-t` option to read that pattern through `badblocks`, completing it in hours rather than in days.

The problem is that I couldn't understand how the `-t` option of `badblocks` works and I got no search results when searching the web for an example of using `badblocks` with `-t` option. From man page, test pattern is a numeric value between 0 and ULONG_MAX-1 (I'm making a wild guess that ULONG_MAX is `2^32`), but I'm not sure how to provide the pattern (decimal? hexadecimal? binary? ASCII string with length < `2^(32/8)`?). And is the pattern size related to block size?

The other part of the problem is to write a script to fill the hard disk with the pattern. I can write a Ruby script to do that, but a one liner bash command piped through `pv` would be nice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Letting `badblocks` write the pattern in the first place should be no slower than writing it any other way. Especially if you use the `-b block-size` and `-c blocks-at-once` options so it doesn't do small reads/writes.

This example overwrites the disk with "random" pattern in 1MiB blocks:

```
badblocks -v -w -t random -b 4096 -c 256 /dev/thedisk
```

If there is a problem with speed, it should have some other cause...

Answer (score 1):

Writing a pattern with one tool and reading it with `badblocks` is not going to be much faster than running badblocks with a single pattern, I imagine.

The pattern needs to be specified in hex, at least that's what I understand from this:
`badblocks -t 0x55 -w [...]`

Source: https://github.com/autotest/ctcs/blob/master/runin/destructiveblocktstrnd

Answer (score 0):

So after some more research, I came up with a way to utilise the `-t` option of badblocks (but you should prefer [frostschutz's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/156877/10137) (I somehow missed to notice the `-c` option while asking this question)).

Write `42` all over the hard disk.

```
yes 4 | tr '\n' 2 | pv -pterb -s 4000G > /dev/sdx
```

Verify through `badblocks`

```
badblocks -vs -t 0x3432 /dev/sdx
```